# InversifyJs error only in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, typescript, webpack, inversifyjs

I'm using Typescript with webpack to create a web application. Recently I switched do inversifyJs DI library.

Only on IE (11) I'm getting an error:
`Missing required @injectable annotation in: MyClassName`

The class is annotated, it does not extend any other class. I also included `Symbol` and `Reflect-metadata` polyfills. Firefox and Chrome handle everything correctly. Does inversifyJs work with IE, if yes what can be the reason of this behavior?

Comment: Can you please create a very basic example that fails only on IE and share the source code? We test InversifyJS on IE 11 as you can see [here](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/remojansen/inversifyjs/build/337/job/p73ad0ebkkpflsmq#L1615).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue, added the "es6-shim" script https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.35.1/es6-shim.js to the html page and it resolved the issue. I will update once I know how this resolves the issue

Comment: That is the correct solution. A polyfill for reflect is required for older browsers.